# On The Subject of Colored Switches

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle

<sup>(This is part of a series of puzzles written for [Timwi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/1480/timwi?tab=profile) for a Secret Santa puzzle exchange, themed around various custom modules for the game *Keep Talking and Nobody Explodes*. No KTaNE knowledge is necessary for any of these puzzles except the final meta; each puzzle resolves to a single word or short phrase.)</sup>

---

## On The Subject of Colored Switches

- 1995 surfer film starring Catherine Zeta-Jones
- Atmospheric effect where solar radiation is trapped
- Cocktail made with peanut liqueur
- Result of a punch in the face
- Seneca chief Otetiani's nickname
- Superhero played by Chadwick Boseman
- Valve promotion including Portal

[image: various colored numbers]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### The final answer is

> Society

The title seems to be a reference to the [KTaNE manual](http://www.bombmanual.com/web/index.html), in which each section begins with "On the Subject Of.."

### Step 1

As a starting point, it seems like

> all the clues should have answers referencing a colour, *but not necessarily the colours in the image below*.

1. 1995 surfer film starring Catherine Zeta-Jones

   > Blue Juice
2. Atmospheric effect where solar radiation is trapped

   > Greenhouse, courtesy of @dcfyj in the comment below
3. Cocktail made with peanut liqueur

   > Brown Bomber
4. Result of a punch in the face

   > Black eye
5. Seneca chief Otetiani's nickname

   > Red Jacket
6. Superhero played by Chadwick Boseman

   > Black Panther
7. Valve promotion including Portal

   > Orange Box

### Step 2

Now

> We need to go deeper. Each of the answers has a word that can be commonly associated with another colour, *this time from the image*. We associate the words with the new colours, in order, and take the nth letter from each word (e.g. white is first, and we take the 4th letter from the corresponding word)

If we list the colours in order:

White 4

> House (from #2), S

Black 2

> Box (#6), O

Yellow 3

> Jacket (#5), C

Orange 3

> Juice (#1), I

Blue 5

> [Bomber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winnipeg_Blue_Bombers) (#3), E  (had to Google that one, was stumped!)

Pink 4

> Panther (#6), T

Red 2

> Eye (#4), Y

All of which spells out

> Society

Thanks to @dcfyj for  the answer to #2, which also  helped point out that I was heading down the wrong path initially

Comment: The Atmospheric effect is very likely Rot13(terraubhfr)

Comment: "Each of the answers has a word that can be commonly associated with another colour, this time from the image." I don't understand how this makes "green" from "greenhouse" link to "white".

Comment: @Corsaka Greenhouse -> house -> White House -> white.